# Remapping ctrl key to double tap l-shift key

Tags: emacs

I am using Emacs and the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key position is a bit problematic.

The only solution I found is to make <kbd>Caps-Lock</kbd> as a additional <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key. This is fine, but I also want the occasional use of <kbd>Caps-Lock</kbd> key. So my solution is to rebind <kbd>Caps-Lock</kbd> to double tap of <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.

My question is how to achieve it in both Windows and Linux?

Comment: Surely this question has nothing to do with Emacs? For starters, a "double tap of Shift" is meaningless to Emacs. I presume that it must have some effect at some level on your system, but that must be something you'll have to deal with at the OS level. I strongly suspect you'd be better off turning this into two separate questions; one aimed at Linux and one aimed at Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) under windows.
There seems to be an equivalent program for linux ([autokey](https://code.google.com/p/autokey/)) but I've never used it.

This .ahk script should do the trick:

```
~SHIFT::
if (A_PriorHotkey <> "~SHIFT" or A_TimeSincePriorHotkey > 400)
{
    ; Too much time between presses, so this isn't a double-press.
    KeyWait, Esc
    return
}
Send {CapsLock}
return
```

Source: [Detect a double key press in AutoHotkey [stackoverflow]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1794299/4266296)