# How to send a key only on double-tap?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, keyboard-events, hotkeys

I know I can use

```
F1::Return
```

to disable the <kbd>F1</kbd> key. But I would like to be able to still use it by simply double-tapping. However, when I try

```
$F1::
if (A_PriorHotkey <> F1 or A_TimeSincePriorHotkey > 400) {
    KeyWait, F1
    Return
}
Send, {F1}
```

(based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1794299/321973)), the first press of <kbd>F1</kbd> passes through while all following ones (including double-taps) are completely ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your quotation marks...

```
$F1::
if (A_PriorHotkey <> "$F1" or A_TimeSincePriorHotkey > 400) {
    KeyWait, F1
    Return
}
Send, {F1}
```